# LIBGDX - Bodies falling down and running slowly on Android but not in desktop

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I found this question: [body falls slowly in any gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285234/body-falls-slowly-in-any-gravity)
made the changes but still not working.

here is the relevant code:

for the camera

```
float w = (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    //Initialize variables
   camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(w/ PPM,h/ PPM,camera);
   //set the position of the camera to the center of the world
    camera.position.set(viewport.getWorldWidth()/2, viewport.getWorldHeight()/2,0);
```

Creating the world

```
 world = new World(new Vector2(0,-24),true);
```

Creating the body

```
 BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(300
            /JungleMasters.PPM,3000/JungleMasters.PPM);

    b2body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
```

code for the world step

```
  world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
```

Comment: Can you add the code for when you step the world physics?

Comment: the code has been edited with the requested info

Comment: Hi, it's possible that its due to low fps on the android device. Try using  world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() 6, 2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is issue is resolved by changing the timestep. Thanks to the comments I was able to figure it out.

```
  private static final float STEP_TIME = 1/60f;
private float accumulator = 0;

private void stepWorld() {
    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    accumulator += Math.min(delta, 0.25f);

    while (accumulator >= STEP_TIME) {
        accumulator -= STEP_TIME;

        world.step(STEP_TIME, 10, 8);
    }
}
```

[This](http://saltares.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/) is an article that explains in details what happens and how to fix this type of issues which is something very common.